# HTML from URL layout error

Tags: c#, pdf, hiqpdf

I'm trying to convert my page to PDF using HiQPDF. The code works fine when I run it on my local machine (through localhost), but when I push it to the server, I receive this error:

> HTML from URL layout error

Here's some example code:

```
HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToFile("https://website.com/12345", filePath);
```

`filePath` is the path where the PDF should be created. Path is correct and the folders are all created. When I go to `https://website.com/12345` as my site, I can view the page fine. Even in incognito. If I simply replace `website.com` with `localhost` it works fine locally.

The error suggests there's a problem with the code of the page.. right? What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this in an Azure web app?  If so, it's not supported.  If you're using Azure it would need to be deployed to a web role running in a cloud service.

> You can use the HiQPdf library in Windows Azure Cloud Services and Virtual Machines but not in Web Sites because the Web Sites run in a restricted sandbox. Using Visual Studio you can easily transform an existing ASP.NET 4.0 or MVC application into a Web Role by adding a cloud service project to the solution containing your project. For this, open your solution, right click on the ASP.NET project and select the 'Add Windows Azure Cloud Service Project' option from menu. Right click on the added cloud service project and select the 'Package' option to produce a package and a configuration file you can deploy as an Azure Cloud Service.

http://www.hiqpdf.com/FAQs.aspx

Comment: Hmm that's odd. I am giving it the full path to the website though. I'm not using localhost or anything like that. I'm giving it the full length. HiQPdf's support was able to generate it fine.